# read integer value in assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm

I have the following procedure for reading a one digit integer from the user:

```
SYS_READ  equ 3
STDIN     equ 0

section .data
msg       db "  eksi: "
msg_len   equ $ - msg

section .bss
num       resd 1
;----------------------     

read_num:
push eax
push ebx
push ecx
push edx

mov edx, msg_len
mov ecx, msg
mov ebx, STDOUT
mov eax, SYS_WRITE
int 80h

mov edx, 4
mov ecx, num
mov ebx, STDIN
mov eax, SYS_READ
int 80h

sub dword [num], 2608     ; attention here

pop edx
pop ecx
pop ebx
pop eax
ret
```

Watching the variable's value within `gdb`, I found out that the value is `2608 + entered_value`. I tried things like subtracting `dword '0'` etc. but no results. How can I read the integer value properly, if  **I need** `num` **to be 4 bytes**?

Comment: Are you taking into account linefeed returned by `SYS_READ`? 2608 is 0A30h which sounds like `'0' + LF` to me .

Comment: `'0'` is dec-48 hex-30 `LF` is dec-10 hex-A. so you say it writes `0A30` to `num`. how can I handle the `LF`?

Comment: I mean that if user enters `'1' + LF` you'll end up having `0A31h` in the buffer. Sure you can just subtract '0A30h' from it and have the result if, and only if, user enters single digit followed by linefeed. This would fail miserably if user enters multiple digits or characters. Of course if you only expect single character in range `'0'` .. `'9'` then your approach is correct. You just need to perform some kind of a range check and return error if user entered something else (e.g. letter, control code, or multiple digits).

Comment: In short, I don't know what's your expected use case but your example works perfectly for very narrow set of values. In real life, though, you want to implement some additional parsing and error checking; most simple being `and dword[num],0FFh`, `sub dword [num], 30h` followed by error processing if value is higher than 9.

Comment: I got what you said already. I don't want to check if the user entered two or more digits. `and` is the thing i was looking for. can you compose an answer so I can accept. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only want a single digit returned by the user so you should ignore everything else in the buffer. With the buffer given in your example you can do the following:

```
and dword[num],0FFh
sub dword[num],30h
```

After this `num` will contain numeric value entered by the user. In case user entered a character, control code or anything non-numeric `num` will be higher than 9; your further error processing should take this into account.

Comment: may be lower than 0, too.

Comment: True, if you perform signed comparison.

Answer (score 1):

hi i'm very new to assembly and had the same problem the following file is obviously not the best solution but it works for me at least with numbers with maximum 9 digits the idea is after sys_read eax holds the number of read bytes so one can use this number to obtain the numeric value for example if the input is 123 than the numeric value is 1*10^2 + 2*10^1 + 3*10^0

```
section .data
section .text
global _ipow
_ipow:
    ; input:
    ; ecx - exponent ( for some reason becoz of
    ; multiplication edx can't be used )
    ; output:
    ; eax - base ^ exponent
    push ecx ; store ecx value
    push edx ; store edx value ( mul )
    mov eax, 1 ; zero exponent
start:
    cmp ecx, 0 ; exit loop condition
    jz finish ; we are done
    mul dword [base] ; eax = eax * base
    dec ecx ; next power
    jmp start ; cycle
finish:
    pop edx ; restore edx value
    pop ecx ; restore ecx value
    ret                         
global _start
_start:
    nop
    ; read input value
    mov eax, 0x03 ; sys_read
    mov ebx, 0 ; stdin
    mov ecx, buf ; memory block
    mov edx, 10 ; number of bytes
    int 0x80 ; syscall
    ; now eax holds the number of bytes read
    dec eax ; discard new line character
    ; now eax holds the number of digits
    mov ebx, 0 ; result
    mov dword [base], 10 ; base 10 system
    mov edx, ecx ; address
    mov ecx, eax ; number of digits
S:
    cmp ecx, 0 ; exit loop condition
    jz F ; we are done
    dec ecx ; exponent
    call _ipow ;
    push ebx ; store ebx
    push edx ; store edx ( mul )
    movzx ebx, byte [edx] ; ascii
    sub ebx, '0'; numeric
    mul ebx ; eax = eax * ebx
    pop edx ; restore edx
    pop ebx ; restore ebx
    inc edx ; next character
    add ebx, eax ; get the numeric value
    jmp S ; cycle
F:
    ; at this point ebx holds the numeric value
    mov eax, 0x1 ; sys_exit
    mov ebx, 0x0 ; error code
    int 0x80 ; syscall
section .bss
    buf resb 10 ; 9 digits + '\n'
    base resd 1 ; numeric system
```

the file is compiled with

```
nasm -f elf -g -F dwarf atoi.asm
ld -m elf_i386 atoi.o -o atoi
```

but probably it's better to look for some other solution how to write properly an atoi function